# Key provided is shorter than 256 bits, only 64 bits provided

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

Since I updated 2FA in order to put trusted device, I get this error after the login and security code entered:

> Key provided is shorter than 256 bits, only 64 bits provided

I updated my `User` entity to add:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private int $trustedVersion;

...

public function getTrustedTokenVersion(): int
{
    return $this->trustedVersion;
}
```

I updated my database to put the new column `trusted_version` and updated `security.yaml` in order to use **scheb/2fa-trusted-device**

I don't think the problem is about 2fa-trusted-device, but I'm a beginner with Symfony and I don't find the solution for the problem.